# Grub for Ubuntu, Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: grub2, uefi, mbr

I'm having troubles getting GRUB to list the Windows 10 entry installed on a separate disk I added later in my system.

First I  installed Windows 7 on an already partitioned MBR disk and then Ubuntu, those 2 work fine.
Then I added another disk and installed Windows 10 but the only way I can boot from is is by selection that disk at startup with a BIOS hotkey and that also work fine but I would like one boot menu where I can select one of the 3 installed OS'es.

Windows 7 and Ubuntu are installed on `/dev/sdf`, an mSATA card and Windows 10 is installed on `/dev/sda`, a regular SATA disk.

Output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `fdisk -l /dev/sdf`

```
Schijf /dev/sda: 223,58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectoren
Disk model: OCZ-VERTEX460   
Eenheid: sectoren van 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sectorgrootte (logisch/fysiek): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
In-/uitvoergrootte (minimaal/optimaal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Schijflabeltype: gpt
Schijf-ID: 2B3D7E44-487D-4001-A204-4CD9B1AA9A45

Apparaat     Begin     Einde  Sectoren Grootte Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1085439   1083392    529M Windows recovery-omgeving
/dev/sda2  1085440   1290239    204800    100M EFI-systeem
/dev/sda3  1290240   1323007     32768     16M Microsoft gereserveerd
/dev/sda4  1323008 468860927 467537920    223G Microsoft basisgegevens
```

```
Schijf /dev/sdf: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectoren
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Eenheid: sectoren van 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sectorgrootte (logisch/fysiek): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
In-/uitvoergrootte (minimaal/optimaal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Schijflabeltype: dos
Schijf-ID: 0x5f6d4ce4

Apparaat   Op.     Begin     Einde  Sectoren Grootte ID Type
/dev/sdf1           2048    206847    204800    100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdf2  *      206848    468991    262144    128M 83 Linux
/dev/sdf3         468992 629614591 629145600    300G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdf4      629614592 976773119 347158528  165,6G  5 uitgebreid
/dev/sdf5      629616640 663171071  33554432     16G 82 Linux wisselgeheugen
/dev/sdf6      663173120 976773119 313600000  149,5G 83 Linux
```

Can anyone give me some pointers? I guess it has something to do with the MBR and GTP combination...

Thanks,

Wim

Comment: Since one drive is gpt and other is DOS(MBR), you have Windows on sda in UEFI boot mode & Windows on sdb probably in BIOS boot mode. Not sure about Ubuntu as it will let you install to MBR but boot in UEFI if you have an ESP - efi system partition on first drive. You cannot mix BIOS(MBR) and UEFI(gpt) unless on sepeare drives, but then can only boot from UEFI boot menu. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, once you start booting in one mode, you cannot switch. Or grub only boots other installs in same boot mode.

Comment: Well I was convinced I had single boot menu (GRUB) that let me do that. Most of the time stuff like that works just fine so I don't know a lot about it but learnt a few things while trying to get something to work. Then I stumbled upon a hybrid combination and thought this was it but this is a setup on a GPT disk with a MBR compatible view for an OS that can't handle GPT.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2/Chainloading

In the end the only option was to convert my old MBR Windows to a GPT bootable one and then install an UEFI bootloader with a Windows install disk.